# If I reference an Image from Docker hub without suffix, which Dockerfile will be exactly used?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

If my local Dockerfile starts with the line

`FROM node:14`

and I want to see the content of the Dockerfile it starts from, which one will be exactly referenced?

If I follow the link of the *FROM node:14* line to

https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

and select *14* then it selects the whole list of version 14 with and without suffix (it does not matter if I click only on *14* or on something else in the same line) and I get to this Dockerfile:

https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/c97bb67fb82bb10fd199cb4c4e57b3ab43605a9c/14/buster/Dockerfile

Now, if I want to check the content of the 14-folder and click on the according breadcrumb (link: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/c97bb67fb82bb10fd199cb4c4e57b3ab43605a9c/14 ) then I get this list:

[image]

I am confused, which Dockerfile is really the origin for my local Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter wich one of these "14, 14-buster, 14.20, 14.20-buster, 14.20.1, 14.20.1-buster, fermium, fermium-buster" you click because they are all the same but with different tags. The Dockerfile link you provided (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/c97bb67fb82bb10fd199cb4c4e57b3ab43605a9c/14/buster/Dockerfile) is actually the one that is used.

The node:14 and node:14-buster tags are just the newest subversions for node 14, which in this case is 14.20 and more specifically 14.20.1. So if it gets updated to 14.20.2, node:14 and node:14.20 will be also updated (with their respective -buster suffixes), but node:14.20.1 will become an older version of node:14.

Comment: Thank you!
If I get it right, it means that node:14 and node:14-buster reference equally the latest 14´s version and will be updated if minor or patch changes.

But if I reference an other version from the line like node:14.20, it will be updated only when the patch version changes. If I want narrow it down more, I reference node:14.20.1 which will be not updated at all.

At the moment they are just in the same line, but node:14 will stay and the rest in the line will change according to the current available version.